# Generating an API Secret

Tags: api, security, secret-key

I have created an API that I only want certain clients having access to. After a bit of research, I found that API Keys and API Secrets are pretty good way of controlling that.

I want to basically generate my own secrets using information I control. For example, if I create the secret `1500315177265-8005550000-System`, the secret itself has information I can reference and validate. From what I understand, it doesn't matter what the secret is, as long as its not shared, and that's what makes it a secret. I can append some long salt values to make it much harder to guess. **Can I use secrets securely this way?**

Along the same lines, I am thinking what the need for the API Key is needed if the secret itself has identifying information. More than likely, I'm missing something here or more APIs would do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to suffer creating this mechanism by your own, you could just use [OAuth](https://oauth.net/2/) for this. Actually by reading how OAuth works, I'm pretty sure that you'll get an overall idea of what the "API Key" is doing.

Long story short. OAuth allows you to create access tokens that will be requested by your users, once the user has asked for an access token, he'll be able to use it to get authenticated on the API. 
You can also configure the duration for these access tokens, for example, let's say that you only want them to be valid for one hour. Then the user will use a new access token every hour, helping you to minimize risks against compromised access tokens.

If you want to take a look at the pipeline used by OAuth, it will be something like this:

The user sends an identifier and a shared secret (see them as username and password). If the identifier and the secret are correct, he'll receive a "refresh token", this token will be used to send requests to the token server to receive new "access tokens". The client sends a request to the tokens server to receive an access token, and now he'll be able to send requests to your API, where he'll use his access token as an identifier, and only if the token is valid, he'll get access to your application.

Maybe you could be curious about expired tokens, for example, What happens when the token has expired? Now our user needs to repeat all process again? No, because if the token has expired, he can just send a new request to the tokens server, sending his refresh token, and he'll get a new token to be used with your API.

I'm pretty sure that you already noticed that your API key is the "access token" equivalent, and your shared secret is the equivalent to the credentials used at the beginning of the OAuth process. 
You can create your own mechanism, but you will need to take a lot of considerations that are already covered by OAuth. For example, Will you expire your API keys? After all, you should not trust a single key to be sent over every request for an undetermined amount of time. How will you handle the process to request new keys? Do you really want your users to send their secret every time they want a new key? Refresh tokens are useful for this.

Comment: I understand the concept of the access/refresh token but it is not suitable for giving third-party clients access to my API. The secret takes care of authentication without the need for expiring access tokens; and since I control the secret, I can expire it at any time. I use access tokens to make sure that the correct user pulls their information. I just want to know how to correctly handle API secrets.

Comment: But if you're using your secret as an authentication mechanism every request, then you're using a long-term secret for that. If the secret gets compromised at any moment, an attacker can get access to your API for an undetermined amount of time. I'm pretty sure that you're thinking "but it's a secret!!", but what about a man-in-the-middle sniffing your user's requests? If he manages to get that value at least once, now he'll gain access to your API, and yes, you can expire the secret, but you'll do it once you know that it got compromised. And that the reason behind the short-term tokens.

Comment: Now, answering your question about why we need the secret and the key. Your key is just an identifier to say "Hey, I'm X!" and the secret is something that proves that you're who you claim to be. Of course, a man in the middle is still a problem here, so what you can do is to send your API key as an identifier, your request, and then also a digital signature for that request using your shared secret. You're never sending your secret, so an attacker cannot forge your signature to start sending requests with your tokens, and since the server also knows the secret, it can verify the signature.

Comment: I was with you until you mentioned digital signature. What do you mean?

Comment: Also, the part about short-term tokens, those can be compromised as well and the attacker will still have access to the API until the token expires. The only variable here is time and once the attacker has access, the damage is done.

Comment: But at least it's compromised only for a short period of time, for example, a token that expires every hour, means that the attacker will get access for 1 hour at most. On the other hand, only using a long-term secret means that an attacker will get access for as long as it takes you to expire the secret (and new tokens can be generated automatically using a tokens server, since you already have a refresh token, while a new secret is something that will be provided manually).

Comment: I understand your point but the APIs I have used don't use temporary secrets. They pretty much stay static and if you lose it, they assign you a new one.

Comment: About digital signatures. Let's imagine that you have a message M, and you're sending it to a web server. How can the server know that the message was really sent by you? Well, you can sign that message using your secret key, the server will receive both, your message and your signature on that message, it'll run a verification process using your public key, and if the result is correct, that means that it's a legitimate message, because only the secret key can create a valid signature, and the attacker doesn't know that secret key.

Comment: You can read about digital signature algorhtms to get more familiar with this (sorry, I ran out of space).

Comment: @EstebanCervantes; but how do you secure the OAuth endpoint?  Are you not in the same position that you started in?

Comment: @DanielPatrick Sorry for the 1 month delay, I'm pretty sure that it might be too late to answer this, but just in case it's still useful for someone else. The only way to connect to the OAuth endpoint is by submitting the Client ID and Client Secret that you provided to your users. They will use those credentials to generate a refresh token, and they will then use that refresh token to request access tokens that will be used to provide access to your API. Anyone can try to connect to your OAuth endpoint, but they still need valid credentials/tokens to be able to retrieve something meaningful.

Comment: @EstebanCervantes; I guess my question is: isn't that same scenario that we're trying to protect against?  In the situation you just described, you're sending a long-term secret (the Client Secret) over the wire repeatedly; as often as the token expires.  Wouldn't a better solution be to hash the secret with some agreed upon method to generate a token, and make *that* token expirable on the server?  It seems that adding a server (OAuth) which does that for you makes it less secure instead of more secure, even if it buys you some convenience.

Comment: @DanielPatrick The Client Secret is only sent when you want to generate a refresh token. Refresh tokens must have a long lifespan because you're going to use them to generate access tokens. Access tokens have a short lifespan, maybe minutes or hours, it depends of the use case. So the only thing you're sending repeatedly is the access token, and it gets expired after a few hours at most. Both the access token and the refresh token get expired on the server, so as soon as you send it and it has already been expired, the server will return an error message saying that the token has expired.